# Ansible does not cancel a job after running into fata error (awx)

Tags: ansible, ansible-awx

I have the following issue concerning ansible (awx):
When a Job fails with `fatal: [IP]: FAILED!`, ansible does not cancel this job and awx keeps displaying "Running" forever. I need to cancel those jobs manual which is quite annoying.
The reason why ansible fails does not matter here.
I've tried to solve this problem by adding

```
- name: Fail task when the command error output prints FAILED
  ansible.builtin.command: /usr/bin/example-command -x -y -z
  register: command_result
  failed_when: "'FAILED' in command_result.stderr"
```

at the top of the playbook, but it won't work.

If you have any ideas...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Playbooks support asynchronous mode, if you need stablish a timeout for your task you can use it. Ansible waits until the tasks either completes, fails or timeout. For this you should use `async` and `poll` parameters, `async` stablishs the timeout for the task and `poll` stablishs the time in wich ansible checks the status of the task. Both must be in seconds.

You could try as below

```yaml
- name: Fail task when the command error output prints FAILED
  ansible.builtin.command: /usr/bin/example-command -x -y -z
  register: command_result
  async: 60
  poll: 15
```

For more information:

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_async.html#asynchronous-playbook-tasks